# How to change model name from singular to plural in working app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I created two models `Stat`, `Setting` with `belongs_to` association to `User` model. Each `User` has association `has_one` to `Stat` and `Setting`. Right now I'm thinking that it would be better and more readable to have models named `Stats`, `Settings`. It seems to be also more English gramatical correct.

My question is how to change it? App is already working. I want to also keep my data in database safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is idiomatic to use singular for the name of the class.

You will have a happier coding experience if you stick to the conventions.

https://gist.github.com/iangreenleaf/b206d09c587e8fc6399e

Comment: What about controller name? I recently changed `RankingsController` to `RankingController` because it has only one index view to display single ranking of users sorted by points. There's no model `Ranking` connected with this controller. Is it good aproach?

Comment: I would do plural.